# Blocking successive SQL requests on the backend

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel, rest

### Context

I am working on an application that has a `AngularJS` front-end and `Laravel` backend with `MySQL` as a database. The backend works basically as a REST API.

### Problem

While working on the search page, **I had a problem, when the user is clicking multiple filters, writing in the search text field or flipping through pages rapidly, multiple requests are sent as the search response is updated automatically without a search button, this slows down the response time dramatically.**

So I tried solving this by cancelling the request if another one if fired.
This is the code using `Restangular`:

```
this.refresh = function(filter) {
    if (abortGet){
        abortGet.resolve(); // cancel the previous call through timeout HttpConfig
    }

    abortGet = $q.defer();
    resource.rest = Service.withHttpConfig({timeout: abortGet.promise}).getList(filter);
    resource.rest.then(function(data) {
        ...
    });
};
```

[image: Image of requests cancelled on the frontend]

The issue is that I think requests still make their way to the backend and so while the front-end part of the request was cancelled, the database is slow.

*I don't want the application to feel unresponsive and so I don't want to block the request sending on the frontend for an amount of time to ensure the user has finished querying.*

### Question

- Is there a way to block requests for MySQL on the backend if successive ones arrive from the same user?
- I assume this is a typical problem with advanced search implementation, are there multiple strategies to deal with it?

Comment: The first thing you do can do is to use a debounce for user input.

Comment: I did this, however, if the request is a little complex, slow to process or if the user is slow while choosing options, multiple requests will be sent. I think I must handle it on the backend somehow.

Comment: I would try using Redis to cache database results.

Comment: @Camilo thank you for your suggestion, we already use Redis to cache most non-rapidly changing data. However, the data I am asking about changes quickly.

Comment: Maybe you can set a [rate limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#rate-limiting) on some of your routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Backend*

If you data doesn't change rapidly a good solution might by adding a reverse proxy to cache rendered results on the web server.

This way if the same URL is requested repeatedly your proxy will serve the already rendered document from cache. Different URL endpoints can be cached under different cache retention depending on the nature of the data.

Nginx has those features built-in and ha-proxy and Pound might also be good alternatives.

*Front-end*

Another solution could be to be a little smarter on the front end i.e. to store results temporarily in memory or the browser-based database IndexedDB. This would help with two typical situations:

1. If a user reverses a filter widget the prior result would be there ready.
2. If a user narrows-down the search you could filter down by filtering the data in the IndexedDB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we already have caching that is being done on the backend using Redis for some non-rapidly changing info, however, for the lists I am asking about, they change rapidly and they contain around 200k records each. _And so, on the backend, would you consider caching the whole list? And if that's the case, would you cache all different configurations of all the existing filters?_

Comment: For the IndexedDB solution, there's something that I don't understand, if the current showing list based on the filters is a subset of the whole list of records in the database based on the chosen filters. How is it that if the user changes the filters, I know that the right information exists in the current subset and so I don't go searching for it on the database? In all the cases, unless, I have all the records in IndexedDB, I can't know for sure. Am I missing something?

Comment: You would keep the results from the more general filter in the IndexedDB and redisplay that instead for querying the API again. The key to the IndexedDB would be your filter settings. You could also keep a timestamp as of which the data was retrieved.

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve 200k records? You should use pagination or Infinit Scroll and only retrieve like 500 records at once.

Comment: @MrWook I am already paginating but the results shown are subject to change based on the filters. So for example, if I cache the first 500 records without any filters, when the user adds a filter, I am not sure that the results for the filter are in those 500 and so I have to do a full search again with the current filter applied against the DB. Later on, if he chose another filter, I will have to re-do the whole request again against the DB. _Do you get the issue? Caching doesn't work unless you cache the whole set of data bcz you are never sure that you results are in the cached subset_.

Comment: @VictorOlex Yup, I think I can cache all results whenever a user takes a step, because I will be sure that whenever he adds another filter, the results are surely a subset of the current results. It just appears to me weird to cache for each step. But thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @kagawish, thanks. If you like the ideas, please accept the answer.